# Regex find XXX if present but not if Y is present too

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to have a regex that finds every string containing "good answer" but not if the string also contains an interrogation mark ("?").

I believe the language to be Ruby (it's for the [ips comment bot](https://github.com/thesecretmaster/ips-comment-bot) on interpersonal.stackexchange.com).

So far, my regex looks like that:

```
((?!\?)(.*?))good\Wanswer((.*?)(?!\?))$
```

Which isn't working... at all.

I also have this version who works on some of the strings I want (but is detecting too many things):

```
good\Wanswer(((?!\?).)*$)
```

---

## Here are the strings I want to detect:

> That a very good answer!

_

> (Other than that, this is a really good answer and I've upvoted it.)

_

> good answer dvdf!

_

> dsds good answer cfds

_

> It is a good answer, but I feel it played into the OP's hands really. You said what they wanted to hear - that they shouldn't *freely* share the information because it is like a child cheating on their homework. It is contrary to the spirit of this site, and I'm not sure that charging a colleague money to learn something work-based from you won't get the OP into trouble with their employer. Imagine if a doctor asked to confer with a fellow doctor in order to help a patient, and they charged each other for the information they shared. They'd be dismissed.

---

## Here are the one I don't want to detect

> Thanks for this good answer! (I upvoted it) However, I still don't understand why I shouldn't mention that I believe whatever? What's the problem with that...

_

> cxvd good answer? zedfs

_

> ezdds? good answer dsf dsf

_

> sdsd? dsfdsf? good answer!

_

> Hi, the question is "**How** to tell blabla when X is my good friend", would you mind be a little more detail about *how* OP should do that when OP still want to be friend with both parties? Also, please take some time to read "[How do I write a good answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3266/21067)

_

> As a side note, here is a link to "[How do I write a good answer?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3266/)

_

> Hi, this sound like a good answer to me, I just have one question though: Where you in a similar situation before where you successfully used this technic? In here it's better to back-up your answer with personal experience (here is a guide to [How to write a good answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer) if you need it)

<sub>Also, if you want to make this not case sensitive, be my guest</sub>

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/IG4nji/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bot is running on Ruby, you may use a regex like

```
(?i)^(?![^?]*\?).*good\s+answer
```

or, if you run the regex against multiline input and do not want to overflow across lines

```
(?i)^(?![^?\n]*\?).*good +answer
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LI8NOT/1).

**Regex details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?![^?]*\?)` - no `?` after any 0+ chars other than `?` is allowed
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `good\s+answer` - `good`, 1+ whitespaces, `answer`.

Comment: How does this prevent matches where the question mark is after "good answer"? (I see it works from the demo, but I can't tell why you don't need to repeat that negated lookahead at the end of the regex as well)

Comment: @scohe001 `(?![^?]*\?)` is executed once at the start of a string/line, and it goes up to the first `?` regardless of where it is, before or after `good answer`. Then, if there is no `?`, matching goes on right from the start of the string.